# What is wrong with my SWIG typemap?

Tags: c++, lua, swig, typemaps

I created a SWIG typemap for my function.

```
%typemap(in) (int width, int height, lua_State *L)
{
    if (!lua_isnumber(L, -1) || !lua_isnumber(L, -2))
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: number expected");
    $1 = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
    $2 = lua_tonumber(L, -2);
    $3 = L;
}
```

But it doesn't work if I try to call the function in Lua.

I call this function like the following in Lua.

`createWindow(500,300)`

I just want to pass `width`, `height` from Lua to this function.

How can I fix the typemap to make it work?

Comment: Actually for a function taking primitive types you don't need a typemap at all.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. So I shouldn't pass `lua_State*` to C++ function? What should I do if I want to use `lua_State*` only inside the specific function and not typemap? Say, I have `void createWindow(int width, int height)`

Comment: @HenriMenke Could you please show me how to do this not using the typemaps? I'm a newbie. please help me.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-argument typemaps won't do the trick here because they are designed to map a single Lua argument to multiple C++ arguments.  You can help yourself with a default argument here.  This is done using `%typemap(default)`.  We tell SWIG to default any `lua_State *L` argument to the instance used by SWIG.

```
%module window

%{
#include <iostream>

void createWindow(int width, int height, lua_State *L) {
    std::cout << "Creating window of size " << width << "x" << height << '\n'
              << "Number of arguments: " << lua_gettop(L) << '\n';
}
%}

%typemap(default) (lua_State *L) {
    $1 = L;
}

void createWindow(int width, int height, lua_State *L);
```

```lua
local window = require("window")
window.createWindow(500,300)
```

```
$ lua5.2 test.lua
Creating window of size 500x300
Number of arguments: 2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you so much Sir.